# AnyLogic’s controls application

Tags: anylogic

I want to use an AnyLogic’s controls such as Combo box and Radio Buttons for changing a parameter from the start. But now I can change the parameter only after the simulation is started. I want Anylogic at first show me the Radio Buttons and I choose the parameter and after that, I start the run.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Experiment objects are for. Please learn how to use them via the tutorials and the [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fexperiments%2FAbout%20Experiments.html&resultof=%22%65%78%70%65%72%69%6D%65%6E%74%22%20%22%65%78%70%65%72%69%22%20)

Essentially, create parameters on Main and replicate them on experiment screens with variables and radio buttons linked to those. Then you can feed the user values to your Main using the experiment properties (section "Parameters").

Note that it is slightly different with cloud experiment setups.